# Upgrade .net core 2.2.0 to 2.2.6 or above

Tags: asp.net-core

Looking for steps to upgrade .Net core 2.2.0 to 2.2.6 or higher (not 3.0)

I am new to .net core. So looking for guidance on how to upgrade .net core 2.2 to 2.2.6 as app is failing while pushing to Pivotal cloud foundry. Our PCF environment dotnetcore buildpack version is 2.2.12; Used to work before using 2.2.5 build pack.  Please find error message below.  To resolve this error , though of upgrading .net core app to versions higher than 2.2.5.  But would like to seek help on steps to follow for upgrading the app & respective dependencies.

Here is targetframework from .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And dependencies are

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="12.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="EFCore.BulkExtensions" Version="2.4.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="8.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Manulife.Logging.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.CloudFoundry.Connector.EFCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.CloudFoundryCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.Extensions.Logging.DynamicLogger" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.Security.Authentication.CloudFoundryCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Error while pushing app to Pivotal (during dotnet publish)

```
depends on runtime.linux-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.2.5) but run 
time is not found. Picked up 2.2.6 which is available 
/tmp/app/Basischangeapp/Basischange.csproj : error NU1605: Detected 
package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetAppHost from 2.2.6 to 2.2.5. 
Reference the package directly from the project to select a different 
version.
```

Comment: What does `dotnet --info` say?

Answer (score 0):

It will happen because of version mismatch between local SDK and the build server.

Add this line to your `.csproj` file:

```
<TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
```

After that, `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` will use `LatestNetCorePatchVersion`.

Comment: I added above line in .csproj , but still getting same error while pushing app to pivotal using cf push which does dotnet publish

Comment: Update the nuget package for Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetAppHost. It might sol ve the problem

Comment: I am thinking to upgrade entire app to .net 2.2.6 or higher instead of individual packages to see if it works. Is there any good link i can follow to upgrade .net core apps from 2.2.0 to higher , please share.

Comment: I didn't said update individual packages. I said update `Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetAppHost`, And then you can update whole app. Error `NU1605` means `Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetAppHost` version downgrade prevents your app to be updated.